# pass text box value from one page to another page without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have two text box i am trying to pass that textbox value from one page to another page with out page refresh i am using ajax for this but i am able to achive only one text box value

Here is my code

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "testing.php?message="+ document.getElementById("message").value+"service="+document.getElementById("city").value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
//return false;
</script>
```

i think i am wrong here in this line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "testing.php?message="+ document.getElementById("message").value+"service="+document.getElementById("city").value, true);
```

How can i achieve my goal

Any help will be apprecieted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string pairs need to be seperated with an ampersand:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "testing.php?message="+ document.getElementById("message").value+"&service="+document.getElementById("city").value, true);
                                                                          //Here -----^
```